# Floquet theory - Decomposition of $A(t)$ matrix

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

I'm trying to classify periodic matrices $A(t)$ where its Floquet decomposition has a finite number of harmonies.

Let $$\dot{x}_1=A(t)x_1 $$

By Floquet Theory, the transition matrix is:
$$P(t)e^{(t-t_0)R} P^{-1} (t_0)$$

The equation that connects those 2 is:
$$A(t)P(t)=\dot{P}(t)+P(t)R$$

Let's declare matrix $A(t)\in\Bbb R^{2\times 2}$ matrix with a finite number of harmonies, for example:

$$A(t)=\begin{pmatrix}-\cos(2wt)&-w-\sin(2wt)\\ w-\sin(wt)& \cos(2wt)\end{pmatrix}$$

**Can I find a specific property about matrix $A(t)$ that can assure me a matrix $P(t)$ with a finite number of harmonies?**

For this example,
$$P(t)=\begin{pmatrix}-\sin(wt)&\cos(wt)\\ \cos(wt)& \sin(wt)\end{pmatrix},
\quad R=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\ 0& -1\end{pmatrix}$$